# Rails: is it a good idea to store the view in a global var?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm thinking of storing the view, what i mean by view is like this:
app/views/profiles/index.html.haml
into this i would do
$view = self

then in other parts of my app i would use and edit the $view var.

it might get troubles?

Comment: Could you provide examples of what you intend to do with this variable?

Comment: i would need to get the url_for in some files...

Comment: Personally, I can't imagine why you would ever want to do what you describe.

Comment: i have a presenter for a model. this presenter has things like url_for(:controller => 'bla bla', :action => 'bla bla') and stuff like that. so i would need that.. then i have smodules, that are some kind of the plugin cells..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some people consider defining global variables in ruby as something very wrong. I concur. Encapsulation is very important.

Think about this for a second - when you start a rails server, global objects are stored in memory for as long as the server is running whereas when you request a php file they last only for the duration of that one request. So this means that in rails, global variables will be shared among all the users. This goes for class variables as well.

So you may never have problems in development, but when you have more than one user at the same time you could be in for some unwanted sideeffects.

Comment: i get it! thanks. so class variables and global vars are shared. it's not so good... :s